# Увеличить все четные числа, содержащиеся в массиве, на исходное значение первого четного числа.C#

Tags: c#

Дан целочисленный массив размера n. Увеличить все четные числа, содержащиеся в массиве, на исходное значение первого четного числа. Если четные числа в массиве отсутствуют, то оставить массив без изменений.
Я пробовал написать код но у меня выводит все не так как надо. Буду благодарен за любой ответ !
Вот что я сделал:

```
 int n = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            int[] arr = new int[n];
            int x = 0;
           
            Random rnd = new Random();
            for(int i = 0;i<n;i++)
            {
                arr[i] = rnd.Next(1, 50);
               

            }
            for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
            {
                if (arr[i] % 2 == 0)
                {
                    arr[i] = x;
                    Console.WriteLine($"{x}");
                }
                else
                {
                   Console.Write(arr[i]);
                }
            }
            for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
            {
                if(arr[i] % 2 == 0)
                {
                   arr[i] = arr[i] + x;
                    Console.WriteLine(arr[i]);
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Из вопроса не ясно, нужно ли первое чётное удваивать. Если да, то `else` просто убрать

```
bool first = true;
int evenadd = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
    if(arr[i] % 2 == 0)
    {
        if (first) {
            evenadd = farr[i];
            first = false;
        }
        else
            farr[i] += evenadd;
    }
}
```